# Integrate Blazor components with Sdk Microsoft.Net.Sdk in the project type "class library"

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, blazor-server-side, class-library

Is it possible to integrate Blazor components in the Microsoft.Net.Sdk, class library project. Target: net7.0. It is a custom plugin in Nocommerce framework.

if I try with the new MVC Web project (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web), everything is working perfectly.

Steps I did:

1. .csproj files:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <AssemblyName>Nop.Plugin.Test</AssemblyName>
        <RootNamespace>Nop.Plugin.Test</RootNamespace>
        <Company>Test</Company>
        <OutputPath>..\..\..\..\test\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Test.Web</OutputPath>
        <OutDir>$(OutputPath)</OutDir>
        <OutNopWeb>$(OutDir)\..\..</OutNopWeb>
        <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
        <NoWarn>1701;1702;IL2121;NETSDK1138</NoWarn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
          <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components" Version="7.0.0" />
          <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web" Version="7.0.0" />

    </ItemGroup>
    
    <PropertyGroup>
        <RazorLangVersion>7.0</RazorLangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- Include your Blazor components here -->
        <RazorCompile Include="$(OutNopWeb)\Themes\Test\**\*.razor" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

2. Startup.cs, Configure method:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        });
}
```

3. Startup.cs ConfigureService method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
}
```

4. Layout.cshtml

```
    <base href="~/" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

5. Index.cshtml

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Nop.Plugin.Test.Web.Themes.Views.Shared.RazorComponents.Component>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered, new { Data = " Hello World " }))
```

Comment: could you pls share the tutorial you followed and introduce what exception you were facing now? Or could you share your end goal?

Comment: I did not found a normal example for class library project. For example, I tried this tutorial for the new MVC Web project and it works perfectly: https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-do-you-use-blazor-in-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-application   If I try in my existing real project, the result which I get: the razor file is not generated and I get an error in the .cshtml file. The decision which I found out and is in my example above was from chat gpt.

Comment: the tutorial you used is [integrating blazor component into .net core mvc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server) project. and your requirement looks like to integrate blazor component into class library. maybe [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) is what you want? It introduces how components can be shared in a Razor class library (RCL) across projects.

Comment: thank you, I tried with it as well, but we can not change the type of the project. It is a big project wich is integrated in another one.

Comment: thanks for your reply... and microsoft only provide such kind of operation in their documents, and I'm afraid we don't have official action to implement your requirement...